# How does cloning work in the snap.svg library?

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I was just going through this [SVG example here](http://snapsvg.io/demos/#globe) and I am confused about a line of code that I saw in the source; the code looks like below:

```
var g = Snap();
g.attr({
    viewBox: [0, 0, 800, 600]
});

Snap.load("map.svg", function (f) {
    function getShift(dot) {
        return "t" + (400 - dot.x) + "," + (300 - dot.y);
    }
    var gr = f.select("g"),
        wrd = f.select("#world").attr({fill: "#fff"}),
        syd = f.select("#sydney").attr({fill: "red"}),
        msk = f.select("#san_francisco").attr({fill: "red"}),
        pth = f.select("#flight"),
        pln = f.select("#plane"),
        top = g.g()
    // DIFF above line of code , what is g.g();
    top.attr({
        mask: g.rect(100, 0, 600, 600).attr({
            fill: "r(.5,.5,.25)#fff-#000"
        })
    });
    top.add(gr);
    var click = top.text(410, 310, "click!").attr({
        font: "20px Source Sans Pro, sans-serif",
        fill: "#fff"
    });
    pth.attr({
        display: "none"
    });
    // DIFF , I am not quite understanding below line of code.
    pln = gr.g(pln, pln.clone());
```

I am not quite sure what is happening at this point of the code here:

```
pln = gr.g(pln, pln.clone());
```

If I try to break it down then I see that `pln` is one of the elements of the SVG as is evident from the line of code `pln = f.select("#plane"),` , and the line of code `pln.clone()`is just cloneing the element as can be seem in the [snap.svg docs](http://snapsvg.io/docs/#Element.clone).

What I am confused about is the `gr.g` part. `gr` I believe as can be seem in the code is the outermost element is the SVG and `g` is an instance of the snap library , so the line `pln = gr.g(pln, pln.clone());` somehow doesn't make sense. Would somebody explain ?

Comment: I'm not seeing that particular construct used in that particular way in the docs. If I had to guess, `gr.g()` creates a `g` element and adds its arguments to that element as described [here](http://snapsvg.io/docs/#Paper.g).

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: Note 'g' at the top of the code is just a variable that has been used for the paper (it would have been better for the variable to be called 'paper' or 's' for Snap). However with gr.g(), g() is a method acting on the variable gr (which in this case is a group). So don't get the variable 'g' confused with the method element.g(), they are very different things. It's really bad naming in this case of the variable.

If we look earlier in the code, Snap has assigned DOM elements via the css selectors, so we end up with variables ...

gr = the first g/group element in the map.svg file thats been loaded
pln = the element within the svg with the id 'plane'.

g() is a group creating function for a Snap element..

So pln = first group element, create a group with g(), and in that group, we will add the original plane, as well as a copy/clone of plane.

So pln was originally an svg element or group representing the plane. Now pln is a a group containing 2 identical planes.

Why has he done this ? I think its to give a slightly different effect. Overlay one plane with no stroke over another with a bigger stroke. (I'm not quite sure why he didn't just have one plane with a big stroke though, maybe it looks a bit different)